# What is the default holo blue background of a MenuItem in the ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, click

For the need of my application, I needed a custom View in the ActionBar (because this view should be modified easily by code)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_custom"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/menu_layout"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

That's not very difficult ;-)

Now the problem is that my View does not react visually to the click anymore.
I know that I could use a custom background with pressed/selected/.. state, but I would like to use the default ACtionBar background, so I am sure I won't break anything on some devices.

I have started looking at ActionBarSherlock and Android source code, but I don't know exactly where to look.

Thank for any help.

Comment: Look at their documentation. Whats the problem? the action bar item is clickable, but it doesnt change background to show it is clicked?

Comment: The problem is simple: Imagine that I use a Button: The background will look like a button while the other ACtionBar items have a transparent background that turn blue when clicked

Answer (score -1, accepted):

These are the action item background selectors from ActionBarSherlock:

```
/res/drawable/abs__item_background_holo_dark.xml
/res/drawable/abs__item_background_holo_light.xml
```

and the corresponding files in the SDK:

```
<sdk>/platforms/android-<version>/data/res/drawable/item_background_holo_dark.xml
<sdk>/platforms/android-<version>/data/res/drawable/item_background_holo_light.xml
```

Answer (score 7):

You can directly use `android:background="?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground"` for the root item of your actionLayout. This will reference to a resource value in the currently applied theme.

Comment: If you ask me, this should be the accepted answer. Major props for using the standard Android background to address this issue.